# Error while creating database in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express. Culture error on windows server 2003 Service Pack 2

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I'm encountering a problem with Microsoft SQL Server express 2008, I'm trying to create a database and I get culture error. Here is what happens when I'm trying to create a database:
[Database creation error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bNqT.png)

And here is a full report about this error:

```
===================================

Culture ID 1155 (0x0483) is not a supported culture.
Parameter name: culture (mscorlib)

------------------------------
Program Location:

at System.Globalization.CultureTableRecord.GetCultureTableRecord(Int32 cultureId, Boolean useUserOverride)
at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverride)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StringComparer.ChangeCollation(String newCollation, Int32 lcid)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetComparerFromCollation(String collationName)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean inServer)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AbstractCollectionBase.get_StringComparer()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase.InitInnerCollection()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.get_InternalStorage()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.GetObjectByKey(ObjectKeyBase key)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SortedListCollectionBase.AddImpl(SqlSmoObject obj)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FileGroupCollection.Add(FileGroup fileGroup)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.FilegroupPrototype.ApplyChanges(Database db)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabaseData.DatabasePrototype.ApplyChanges(Control marshallingControl)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateDatabase.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)
```

I've tried to reset everything to default settings and I still get this error, I've tried to reinstall .NET frameworks and same result, I've tried to update .NET frameworks and nothing. I've tried googling about my problem and I found nothing, normally I search for an answer but now I have no where to go so I decided to ask the question here. Oh and I'm running Windows Server 2003.

Comment: what .NET framework are you using

Comment: I was using .NET framework 3.5 and later I updated to .NET framework 4

Comment: How are you creating the new DB? Script or GUI?

Comment: I'm using GUI to create databases

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by uninstalling SQL server and .NET frameworks and then I've redownloaded .NET frameworks and SQL server and installed them again and the problem was gone. Thanks for trying to help me, I really appreciate